# Federated table of two LEFT JOIN tables not working

Tags: mysql, federated-storage-engine

For some reasons I am getting the following error when executing the below query:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ENGINE=FEDERATED' at line 35

```
CREATE TABLE users AS (
  SELECT
    ID, user_email, user_registered,
    first_name.meta_value as first_name,
    last_name.meta_value as last_name,
    telephone.meta_value as telephone,
    country.meta_value as country,
    company.meta_value as company,
    address.meta_value as address,
    city.meta_value as city,
    professional_title.meta_value as professional_title,
    state.meta_value as state,
    areas_of_interest.meta_value as areas_of_interest
    FROM wp_users
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS first_name ON first_name.user_id=ID
        AND first_name.meta_key='first_name'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS last_name ON last_name.user_id=ID
        AND last_name.meta_key='last_name'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS telephone ON telephone.user_id=ID
        AND telephone.meta_key='telephone'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS country ON country.user_id=ID
        AND country.meta_key='country'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS company ON company.user_id=ID
        AND company.meta_key='company'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS address ON address.user_id=ID
        AND address.meta_key='address'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS city ON city.user_id=ID
        AND city.meta_key='city'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS professional_title ON professional_title.user_id=ID
        AND professional_title.meta_key='professional_title'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS state ON state.user_id=ID
        AND state.meta_key='state'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS areas_of_interest ON areas_of_interest.user_id=ID
        AND areas_of_interest.meta_key='areas_of_interest'
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CONNECTION "*****";
```

Note: FEDERATED Engine is on and working on other non-joined table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:
CREATE statements for FEDERATED tables require an additional piece of data called the CONNECTION.  Not having that data in your statement is the source of the syntax error.

Long answer:

For this particular instance, a VIEW would be a better tool than a FEDERATED table.

The FEDERATED storage engine can be though of kind of like symbolic linking in Linux or shortcuts in Windows.  It is primarily used to access a table on a server that doesn't actually store the table locally, but on a different mysql server.  For that reason, when you create a FEDERATED table, you also have to include the CONNECTION that the FEDERATED storage engine should use in the CREATE statement.  You can opt to create a FEDERATED table on the same host that the data is stored, but it'll result in additional overhead caused by the unnecessary steps taken to access local data.  Please see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html) for more details.

A VIEW, on the other hand, is like a stored query that executes whenever you query the VIEW table.  [This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) can give you more information on it.

Comment: I forgot to include the connection string in my question but I have it and tried with on the original query. still the same error..

Comment: The FEDERATED storage engine works on one-to-one matching.  The table structure that exists on your remote mysql server must be faithfully duplicated on your local mysql server with only difference being the storage engine part.

Comment: Let's say I have a table called meta_value that exists on Server A and I want to be able to query it on Server B.  I'd first issue this command on Server A: SHOW CREATE TABLE meta_value;  I'd take the resulting create statement (except the engine part), and paste it in Server B.  Then I'd add the FEDERATED information at the bottom.

Comment: Each table that exists on Server A that I want to be able to query on Server B must be "recreated" as a FEDERATED table on Server B.  Then you can do the joins.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. what if the tables are on the same server db and need to sync the above left-joined tables with other than federated method? what is your suggested solution?

Comment: Well I think View is worked perfect for me so far. Many thanks to bring my attention.